# ASP.NET MVC: Attribute to permission to access according to a specific business-rule

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to restrict access in some actions according to some specific conditions for each of them. For this, I thought of using some attribute, similar to `[Authorize]`, for example.

However, searching, perhaps for the wrong term, I could not find something that could help me, where each attribute I would customize the business-rule and check if it is possible to access that Action or not - if it is not possible the page is redirected to another.

There are several Action with these same situations and so I wanted to use the attribute idea to not have to do the verification within each Action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a specific Role and after use it for your user.

To restrict access just write attribute above Action in your controller :
`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager,User,Director")]`, where Admin, Manager, User, Director are users who have access to this Action.

Comment: The issue is not in relation to permission to access a particular page but rather a specific business rule. For example, access a specific page only if the software contains a license for the module that page needs. I would like to know if there is a similar solution to [Autorizhe].